esp32 Ethernet ip=0.0.0.0.0 problem
I'm using esp-idf 4.3.1
My config:
# Example Configuration
#
CONFIG_EXAMPLE_USE_INTERNAL_ETHERNET=y
# CONFIG_EXAMPLE_USE_DM9051 is not set
# CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ETH_PHY_IP101 is not set
# CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ETH_PHY_RTL8201 is not set
CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ETH_PHY_LAN8720=y
# CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ETH_PHY_DP83848 is not set
CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ETH_MDC_GPIO=23
CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ETH_MDIO_GPIO=18
CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ETH_PHY_RST_GPIO=5
CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ETH_PHY_ADDR=0
# end of Example Configuration

My ethernet code:
#include "esp_system.h"  // Include for esp_read_mac
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_eth.h"
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "esp_eth_phy.h"

// Ethernet configuration macros

#define ETH_ADDR        0
#define ETH_POWER_PIN  -1  
#define ETH_MDC_PIN    23
#define ETH_MDIO_PIN   18
#define ETH_TYPE       ETH_PHY_LAN8720
#define ETH_CLK_MODE   ETH_CLOCK_GPIO17_OUT  
#define ETH_RST_PIN    5    
#define TAG            "ETHERNET"



void init_ethernet(void)
{
    
    if (ETH_POWER_PIN != -1) {
        gpio_pad_select_gpio(ETH_POWER_PIN);
        gpio_set_direction(ETH_POWER_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
        gpio_set_level(ETH_POWER_PIN, 1);  
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(10));     
    }

    
    eth_mac_config_t mac_config = ETH_MAC_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
    eth_phy_config_t phy_config = ETH_PHY_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
    phy_config.phy_addr = ETH_ADDR;
    phy_config.reset_gpio_num = -1;  
    
    esp_eth_mac_t *mac = esp_eth_mac_new_esp32(&mac_config);
    esp_eth_phy_t *phy = esp_eth_phy_new_lan8720(&phy_config);

    
    esp_eth_config_t config = ETH_DEFAULT_CONFIG(mac, phy);
    esp_eth_handle_t eth_handle = NULL;
    esp_err_t ret = esp_eth_driver_install(&config, &eth_handle);
    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Ethernet sürücüsü kurulamadı: %s", esp_err_to_name(ret));
        return;
    }

    
    esp_netif_config_t netif_config = ESP_NETIF_DEFAULT_ETH();
    esp_netif_t *eth_netif = esp_netif_new(&netif_config);
    if (esp_netif_attach(eth_netif, esp_eth_new_netif_glue(eth_handle)) != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Ethernet netif bağlanamadı");
        return;
    }

    
    ret = esp_eth_start(eth_handle);
    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Ethernet başlatılamadı: %s", esp_err_to_name(ret));
        return;
    }
    
    

    
    esp_netif_ip_info_t ip_info;
    
    if (esp_netif_get_ip_info(eth_netif, &ip_info) == ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "IP Adresi: " IPSTR, IP2STR(&ip_info.ip));
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Alt Ağ Maskesi: " IPSTR, IP2STR(&ip_info.netmask));
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Ağ Geçidi: " IPSTR, IP2STR(&ip_info.gw));
    } else {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "IP bilgisi alınamadı");
    }

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Ethernet başarıyla başlatıldı.");
}

void get_esp_mac_address(void)
{
    uint8_t mac_addr[6];
    esp_read_mac(mac_addr, ESP_MAC_ETH); 
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ESP32 MAC Adresi: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
             mac_addr[0], mac_addr[1], mac_addr[2], mac_addr[3], mac_addr[4], mac_addr[5]);
} 

ip->0000, how can I fix that?

Hello and welcome.  It's not clear what you're saying your problem is or what question you want to ask.  You say some IP address is 0.0.0.0, but where?  And what makes you say it needs fixing, it's a legitimate address in many circumstances.

You need to put a static address into ip_info.ip, or enable the DHCP client and wait for event.  Sorry that the question was closed before it could be answered.

I have a specific MAC-to-IP address, such as 10.34.82.21. When my device is in AP mode, it should reconnect via Ethernet using the assigned IP. I'm a newbie and currently an undergraduate—apologies for any confusion.
